# User control property not reachable from indirect call

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework

I try to do some actions on many of my controls during a sub. However I have some troubles to access to properties of my custom UserControl.
Here is part of generic code:

```
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
                CheckBoxes_CheckStateChanged(ctrl, e)
            End If
            If TypeOf ctrl Is MyUserControl Then
                ctrl.MyProperty = true
            End If
        Next
```

This is working properly for CheckBox part but MyUserControl part is not usable: MyProperty is not proposed or not reachable.

How can I reach and affect a value to the property of my custom UserControl in an automatic way?

PS: I work on compact framework

Comment: Matt answer works perfectly.
In addition if I want do more several action it's easier to do:

Dim MyUserControl_N as MyUserControl = New MyUserControl
MyUserControl_N = CType(ctrl, MyUserControl)

and then use MyUserControl_N as user control selectionned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast ctrl as its type is control

```
If TypeOf ctrl Is MyUserControl Then
    CType(ctrl, MyUserControl).MyProperty = true
End If
```